# If $A^2$ is orthogonal is it true that $A$ is also orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If $A^2$ is orthogonal what can we say about $A$?

Can we also claim that $A$ is orthogonal?

---

Note that since $A^2$ is orthogonal it is diagonalizable. Can we use the fact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot claim that since this is a false! Just take some matrix $A$ such that $A^2=I$.

Take for instance
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Hi! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat, Hi!